Typescript how to get type of optional properties of class or interface
class Load  {
    ID: number;
    Action?: string;
    public getType(name: string) {
    return typeof this[name];
    }

    constructor() { }
}

    let _load =new Load()
    _load.ID = 5

    console.log(_load.getType("ID")) // It logs number
    console.log(_load.getType("Action")) //It logs undefined. But it should be string for me

I want to get types of all properties in my class regardless of it has a value or not. But if optional properties haven't been set, getType always return undefined.
I can user Interface instead of Class, doesn't matter. How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!
Edit : My main goal is like below.
I will have data from backend service which have some format as a model like Load interface or class. Some properties of Load will be number or string and can be optional (so null or undefined). And I want to show this fields and are edited this fields by user from html and post them back to backend service to save. But when I'm saving, I want to preserve my model. I mean if any field is number, it has to still be number after user's update and It should be sent to backend endpoint as number. I was using   in html for every field. Because I want to do dynamic html for each property of type with ngFor iteration. But to preserve value type (if it's a number, it should stay as a number), I need to check and know type of property to put  instead of . So my main goal is just preserving data type dynamicly according to my interface or class.I don't want to cast each field by manually. If is there any different solution to succeed it, I'll be glad to hear.
Thanks again!

The typeof you use here is the Javascript's typeof. It lacks the information about Typescript types since the information is removed during the compilation and is lost.

There's nothing string-like about Action at runtime if it's undefined.Why do you need runtime information about a compile time feature? TS works the other way around, more or less. Please [edit] to give more information about the underlying use case. As asked, the answer to this question is "this is impossible", which is probably not helpful to you. This is likely to be an XY problem, where you have an underlying use case and you think that getting runtime type info about undefined properties is the solution. Maybe there's a better solution we can suggest.

Until you give value to the "properties", The value are undefined, so "Javascript" can not know the value. e.g. if you don't add the _load.ID = 5, _load.getType("ID") logs also "undefined"

@jcalz I edited by typing my main goal. Thanks for all response. Can you check it again?

It seems your problem is that your raw data model (think of it as plain JSON) does not have enough information for you to properly render your html form.  Specifically, it doesn't have type information for fields with undefined values.

In this case, I think you need to provide the "form configuration" separately from the data model.  Maybe your model could include a "type" field that allows you to "look up" the form configuration.
You may find the ngx-formly package useful in creating dynamic forms in Angular.

I wish I could see a [mre] of the code you're trying to use that cares about the type of something undefined. I'm afraid the paragraph of text doesn't explain it enough for me (although I know nothing about angular so I'm happy to disengage). If you need such info at runtime then you're going to need some runtime object that looks like a schema, possibly as shown in this playground link. But that might be more machinery than you want. Let me know how you want to proceed.

Because you set the value to ID you get number type, else that will also be undefined. Instead just go for initializing the property on the top of the class or on the constructor, this will give you the desired type always.
class Load {
  ID!: number;
  Action?: string;
  public getType(name: string) {
    return typeof (this as any)[name];
  }

  constructor(ID: number, Action = '') {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Action = Action;
  }
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

class Load {
  ID!: number;
  Action?: string;
  public getType(name: string) {
    return typeof (this as any)[name];
  }

  constructor(ID: number, Action = '') {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Action = Action;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    let _load = new Load(1);

    console.log(_load.getType('ID')); // It logs number
    console.log(_load.getType('Action')); //It logs undefined. But it should be string for me
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I know that if I set any value to Action, I can get the type of it. Problem is that some properties can be undefined and should stay as undefined. So, I can't assign empty string to them in constructor. If it's undefined and hasn't be touched by user, It should be sent back to backend endpoint as undefined not an empty string.

@onceinanbluemoon You did not explain the problem properly, the original code is fine then, please explain in simple terms what the problem is.
